# Swift: Google Map API Camera and MapView

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

With some online help, I successfully have implemented some Google map features in my iOS app.

```
extension GoogleMapViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
    func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace) {
        searchController?.active = false
        // Do something with the selected place.
        print("Place name: ", place.name)
        print("Place address: ", place.formattedAddress)
        print("Place attributions: ", place.attributions)

        // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
        // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        view = mapView

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
        marker.title = place.formattedAddress
        marker.map = mapView
    }
}
```

I believe I have got the `place.formattedAddress` from search bar but how do I retrieve its coordinate so that I could set the camera and marker to show the searched place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place.html#a3dc43865df0de69b6b1203a15a745efc), you can get the location using `place.coordinate`

```
let currentPlace: CLLocationCoordinate2D = place.coordinate
```

Then you can get its latitude and longitude as `currentPlace.latitude` and `currentPlace.longitude` respectively

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d)

Comment: I tried "mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: place.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)", but it doesn't work.

Comment: `place.coordinate` returns a `CLLocationCoordinate2D `. I've updated my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

```
To set the camera position at particular place , first we have to declare a object of CLLocationCoordinate2D and then get the latitude and longitude of that particular place .

var currentPlace:CLLocationCoordinate2D = place.coordinate 

Now you are able to get the latitude and longitude by writing currentPlace.latitude and currentPlace.longitude .

Since you have lat/lon , you can easily set the camera position on that place .

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(currentPlace.latitude, longitude: currentPlace.longitude, zoom: 6.0)

let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    view = mapView
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way.

```
func resultsController(resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace) {
    searchController?.active = false
    // Do something with the selected place.
    print("Place name: ", place.name)
    print("Place address: ", place.formattedAddress)
    print("Place attributions: ", place.attributions)

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(place.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    view = mapView

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = place.coordinate
    marker.title = place.formattedAddress
    marker.map = mapView
}
```